# Fermat's Factorization using extremely large integers

Tags: python, factorization

I'm trying to implement Fermat's Factorization for very large integers and I can't seem to get it to work.

The code I have is as follows

```
def isqrt(n):
    x = n
    y = (x + n // x) // 2
    while y < x:
        x = y
        y = (x + n // x) // 2
    return x

def FermatsFactorization(N):
    a = math.ceil(isqrt(N))
    b2 = ((a*a) - N)
    while not isqrt(b2).is_integer():
        a += 1
        b2 = ((a*a) - N)
    p = a + isqrt(b2)
    q = a - isqrt(b2)
    print p
    print q
    return p,q
```

So this code can work for simple integers such as 5959, but I wanna factor the following

N =
21782178510063776461241988741393403748263149606418470290457970869584937331514019374606465366303005016660193541806517181777318162895347539817622285020192774759478269128757372541938236369238616095442740118695407004519767912490482867488611536705877428644997287974943888081383661776269804618969459352629702475787077033241358667142820088780464925538022629953746785180882881018116846435825219064338036769722076725591665293793855682103585288579694301648980485573448067751223659912804906632104733676877199934241937423870885559163031690669390029458536950673319993077233987061166029740639193164051093517111904059841571819466949

And when I attempt to run the code I get an error

```
 line 108, in FermatsFactorization
   b2 = ((a*a) - N)
OverflowError: long int too large to convert to float
```

Does anyone know a way around this or if there's some trick to implementing a factorization this large?

Comment: `math.ceil` returns a *float* in Python 2... but is it really necessary? I believe `isqrt` always returns an `int` anyway...

Comment: The *while* loop seems overkill: only an increment of 1 can be required. Converting the ceil result (if really necessary) to an int should solve the problem.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Okay that fixed it from what I can tell. However, it appears to be taking a really long time to factor. How long should it take to factor a number of that size?

Comment: @JCD your test case is 617 digits long. Unless this is made up of many smaller primes, it could take days, weeks, months, even years with the a really good algorithm. Your approach on a powerful computer could take over a 100 years. To see where I'm getting at, check out the [Quadratic Sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_sieve) and if you are feeling really ambitious check out the [General number field sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve). It's a good thing that this isn't an easy task as most of your private information is based off of this difficulty.